# Variables dinámicas utilizando un mapa con boostrappage. Shiny rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio, shiny

Mi objetivo es crear unas variables dinámicas con shiny y, al mismo tiempo, tener un mapa de fondo. Desde que utilice el bootstrapPage no hace el cambio dinámico. Las dos variables que tiene que cambiar (mes y día) no lo hacen. Quería preguntar si el problema esta en el boostrapPage o en otra cosa.

Este seria mi código. Si es necesario otro tipo de imagen o pasar el código directo, por favor díganmelo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]